# Python y OpenCV Convolución y normalización de imágenes

Tags: python, matrices, opencv

me han pedido en clase que haga un programa cuyo enunciado es:

Crear un programa en OpenCV que permita llevar a cabo operaciones de
convolución de una imagen en tonos de gris, empleando una matriz cuadrada de
números en coma flotante, de tamaño variable. Dicha matriz se especificará como
una lista de listas de la siguiente forma:

```
conv = [ [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
         [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
         [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
```

El propio programa será encargado de normalizar el resultado para que se
encuentre en el rango 0-255, y de visualizar tanto la imagen original como la
imagen convolucionada. Indique en los comentarios del programa la estrategia
empleada en el proceso de normalización.

Después de mucho buscar, no he encontrado nada que me funcione, ¿alguien sabé por dónde puedo empezar a meterle mano?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Edit:

Ya tengo la parte de convolución, solo me falta la normalización en el rango 0-255.

Convolución:

```
ruta = ("C:/Users/josea/Desktop/PIVpr4/" + im)
im = cv2.imread(ruta, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('Normal', im)
a = [ [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
           [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
           [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
kernel = np.asarray(a)
dst = cv2.filter2D(im, -1, kernel)
cv2.imshow('Convolución', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Has leído la documentación de OpenCV [sobre convoluciones](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) o sólo has buscado una solución ya hecha?

Comment: Acabo de editar el post con lo que llevo hasta ahora, que ahí se ve mejor que aquí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el código que has puesto, en muchos casos la imagen ya saldrá normalizada (puesto que el kernel que aplicas es para detectar bordes y donde los haya dará como resultado 255 y donde no los haya dará 0). Puedes comprobar si es así imprimiendo los valores mínimo y máximo del array `dst`. He aquí un ejemplo con la imagen del perro que pongo más abajo:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ruta = "perro.jpg"
im = cv2.imread(ruta, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
a = [ [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
      [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],
      [ -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] ]
kernel = np.asarray(a)
dst = cv2.filter2D(im, -1, kernel)
print(dst.min(), dst.max())
```

> 0 255

No obstante, puedes normalizarlo (aunque quedará igual en este caso) con `cv2.normalize`. A ésta hay que pasarle como primer parámetro la imagen origen, como segundo parámetro otra imagen que en este caso no usamos y será `None`, los valores mínimo y máximo que queremos para la imagen resultante (0 y 255) y el tipo de normalización a realizar, que en este caso será MINMAX. Así:

```
norm = cv2.normalize(dst, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
print(norm.min(), norm.max())
```

> 0 255

Si ésta es la imagen de entrada:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='perro.jpg')
```

> [image: Perro]

Este sería el resultado tras la convolución y normalización (aunque en este caso la normalización no varía el resultado, es decir, la convolución sin normalizar también se vería así):

```
cv2.imwrite("norm.png", norm)
Image(filename="norm.png")
```

> [image: Resultado normalizado]

Pero el que el resultado de la convolución esté entre 0 y 255 depende de qué imagen uses como input, y del kernel que utilices para convolucionar. Veamos otro ejemplo.

Usando el mismo kernel, pero sobre una imagen que no tenga bordes como esta:

[image: Borroso]

el resultado de la convolución da valores entre 0 y 21 en este caso.

No pongo la imagen resultante porque se ve básicamente negra.

Aquí sí tiene sentido normalizar y tras hacerlo el resultado "amplifica" las diferencias, de modo que los pixeles que valían 21, pasan a 255. Este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]